# Making Live Distribution from a running Linux OS (Debian)

Tags: linux, debian, livecd

I am running a Debian based linux i386. I downloaded, configured and installed snort. I also changed the desktop background and added a few files in the only user's home folder.

I want to turn that running Debian linux into a live boot, so when they boot it up they have everything looking just like I have the system running. Similar to how Kali works, in the sense that the applications are all there and installed, and it has a custom background etc.

Does anyone know how to do that? I have found plenty of links on making a liveboot of a linux distro, but it lacks the customization that I need and want.

Comment: It might be worth checking into: [remastersys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remastersys) (now called [Respin](http://www.remastersys.org/)).  This has changed hands a few times, so I'm not sure what it's current status is, but it at least used to be the commonly mentioned tool for remastering Debian/Ubuntu from an existing installation and creating a LiveCD/LiveUSB.

Answer (score 4):

I also tried to do this. If I understand your question, you want to turn your current install into a live cd. [*Live Helper*](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/create-your-own-live-linux-cd-or-usb-distribution/) might help and [here](http://willhaley.com/blog/create-a-custom-debian-live-environment/) they explain how to build Debian from command linem it might also help. You could copy your downloaded Debian packages over. Also, squashfs looks promising, but I have never used it. It is used by Ubuntu.

> Downloading and installing Live-Helper:
>
> 1. Open a terminal and type sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
>
>    Add deb http://live.debian.net/debian/ etch main to the list and save the >file.
> 2. Back at the terminal, type sudo apt-get update
> 3. Type sudo apt-get install debian-unofficial-archive-keyring
> 4. Type sudo apt-get install live-helper
>
> Configuring the settings for your Debian based Live CD:
>
> 1. Login as root and open a terminal (must be done as root user)
> 2. From the terminal, type lh_config
>
> Now we can edit the configuration files that have been created in (root's Home) debian-live/config/ directory
>
> Open debian-live/config/chroot, Set the interactive parameter >LIVE_INTERACTIVE="enabled" (this allows you to chroot to the filesystem and make >changes before it is compressed)
>      You should also set the live package to install. For example: >LIVE_PACKAGES_LISTS="gnome" (will install the gnome desktop)
>       Save changes and close the chroot file
>
> Note: To create a USB Image instead of an ISO, open debian-live/config/binary and >change the image type parameter from iso to usb-hdd LIVE_BINARY_IMAGES="usb-hdd"
>
> Building the Debian based Live Linux ISO or IMG:
>
> Now that we have made a couple of basic configuration changes we can proceed with >the build process.
>
> 1. Back at the terminal type cd debian-live (moves us to debian-live, where our >live distro is going to be built)
> 2. Type lh_build (starts the build process based on our live configuration >settings)
>
> During the build process, live-helper will create a directory named chroot >containing the Linux filesystem that will later be compressed. Once live-helper >has finished installing the core components, it will start an interactive shell (change root directory to chroot) pausing the build and allow you to install >additional packages and make changes or adjustments before it compresses the >filesystem and builds the final Live Linux ISO.
>
> 3. At the terminal, when the script responds with the following:
>      Pausing build: starting interactive shell…
>
>    make your changes, if any and then type exit to allow live-helper to continue.
>
> Burn the ISO and test your new creation:
>
> Once live-helper has finished, you'll find your completed ISO in the debian-live directory.
>
> 1. Burn the ISO to a CD or DVD
> 2. Test your new creation by rebooting from the CD/DVD.
>
> Or to Copy the IMG to the USB device:
>
> 1. From the terminal type fdisk -l and locate your USB device. Example: dev/sdX (where X represents your USB device)
> 2. Type dd if=binary.img of=/dev/sdX
> 3. Reboot your PC, booting from the USB device
>
> Note: With your CD/DVD or USB build, you can save your changes back to a USB device via the persistent feature. Simply create a partition on the device labeled casper-rw and type live persistent at boot to enable saving and restoring of settings/changes.
>
> Example: mkfs.ext2 -L casper-rw /dev/sdx2

Comment: Okay, will do. I'll grab some commands

Comment: Awesome, I look forward to trying this